# no puedo usar uialertcontroller en una uicollectionviewcell

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

estoy tratando de ejecutar una accion con alerta en mi celda, pero no sucede nada

```
  @IBAction func btneliminar(sender: AnyObject) {

    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Eliminar", message: "Esta a punto de eliminar una cancion", preferredStyle: .Alert)
    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Si", style: .Default, handler: {(action) in
        let cancion: Cancion = DataBaseManager.sharedInstance.getSongByKey( "id", value: Int(self.lblid.text!)!)
    DataBaseManager.sharedInstance.deletesong(cancion)
    DataBaseManager.sharedInstance.saveSongsDatBaseChanges(
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    })
    alert.addAction(action)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .Cancel, handler: nil))
    self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

}
```

cuando no coloco la alerta si completa la accion, pero cuando esta la alerta, no funciona el boton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es probable que tengas algo mal definido en la linea:

```
let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Si", style: .Default, handler: {(action) in
        let cancion: Cancion = DataBaseManager.sharedInstance.getSongByKey( "id", value: Int(self.lblid.text!)!)
    DataBaseManager.sharedInstance.deletesong(cancion)
    DataBaseManager.sharedInstance.saveSongsDatBaseChanges(
        self.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    })
```

Ya que al ejecutar todo lo demás (Con algunas correciones de mayusculas para swift3)

```
    @IBAction func btnEliminar(_ sender: Any) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Eliminar", message: "Esta a punto de eliminar una cancion", preferredStyle: .alert)

    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Si", style: .default, handler: {(action) in
        print("Elimina")
    })
    alert.addAction(action)

    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "No", style: .cancel, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Funciona perfectamente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El boton esta dentro de la celda, en la vista si funciona osea fuera de la colleccion, pero dentro de la celda solo elimina, mas no muestra el mensaje

Comment: @AlxMrcer Modifiqué la respuesta inicial quizá el botón lo tienes ejecutado mas de una acción, revisa el storyboard.